# How to send Firebase Cloud Messaging from a node server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to send notifications from `FCM` from a `node.js` server?

I haven't found anything about it inside documentation.

Answer (score 33):

Sending messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging takes calling an HTTP end point as described in the [documentation on sending downstream messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream).

Something as simple as this could do the trick:

```
var request = require('request');

function sendMessageToUser(deviceId, message) {
  request({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' :' application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key=AI...8o'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(
      { "data": {
        "message": message
      },
        "to" : deviceId
      }
    )
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { 
      console.error(error, response, body); 
    }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
      console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage+'\n'+body); 
    }
    else {
      console.log('Done!')
    }
  });

sendMessageToUser(
  "d7x...KJQ",
  { message: 'Hello puf'}
);
```

Update (April 2017): you can now also run code very similar to this in Cloud Functions for Firebase. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: Thanks! but which is the variable YOUR_API_KEY_HERE?? I don't know how to get that key from FCM console...

Comment: In console, Gear icon > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging there you will see your API key (server key).

Comment: I am trying this out and I dont get an error, but I'm not seeing the notifications either. Is there a possible reason for this? I tried a specific deviceId as well as a topic... the quickstart example uses "/topic/news" so i did that one. *** for ios btw, but the parameters are the same i think...

Comment: Hi, have you got a simple sample of this implementation from client side? How can I get the deviceId?

Comment: How can I send notification to all users (all device Ids)? I can send to single device, using the mentioned method, and working fine. Struggling since 2-3 days and searching all over. @FacundoLaRocca Device Id is the unique id for a specific device which you can get when registering FCM. How exactly you're developing the app?

Comment: Hi Frank, is there an update to this answer since Google Cloud Next '17?  I want to send a message to an iOS/Android phone based on a cloud triggered event (HTTP Request).

Comment: You could run the same code in a Cloud Function. For an example of that, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Answer (score 9):

```
//I done by this code using node- gcm module.
//We're using the express framework and the node-gcm wrapper

var express = require('express');
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
//init express
var app = express();
app.get('/push', function (req, res) {
    var message = new gcm.Message({
        data: { key1: 'hello' },
        notification: {
            title: 'SPECOZ Offers1',
            body: 'body_data'
        }
    });

    // Set up the sender with you API key, prepare your recipients' registration tokens.
    var sender = new gcm.Sender('Api_Key');
    sender.send(message, 'device_token', function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error:", err);


        }

        else console.log("Response:", response);
        res.send(response);
    });

});
app.listen("pass the port number");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
  const payload = { 
   notification: {
        title: 'this is title', body: 'this is body'
    },
   data: {
           balance: 100,
          priceplanId: 1235 
  }
}  
const deviceToken ='yourtoekn' | ['yourtoekn'];
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, newpayload)
                .then((_response) => console.log(_response))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

*emphasized text*
You can send a notification to both ios and Android devices;