# Firebase notification on child added/modified

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to generate a push notification (if the app is not in the foreground) on firebase db changes? I started coding an android app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firebase provides a tool called *Cloud Functions*.

With this, you can listen to your Firebase Database and send Notifications without the need for an external server :)

See : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases

Comment: is it needed a blaze plan for accessing Cloud function? @Valentin

Comment: Check the Firebase pricing (https://firebase.google.com/pricing). You have 125k calls per month for free.

Comment: I found out that Cloud Functions are free for all internal call Api, but in Log section of firebase however is showed message for billing. It is only a warning

Answer (score 7):

To do it in a simple way, you can use a Service, in this Service you can set a Listener on a ref in your firebase DB when the event is triggered you can create a notify and show it to the user.

This is a very simple tutorial:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-tutorial-using-firebase/

Answer (score 4):

There certainly is. Just have your Android app write the notification request into the database.

Sending device-to-device notifications is not a supported scenario in Firebase Cloud Messaging (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging/37993724#37993724)), so you'll need a server component for that. For an example of how to send a push notification in nodejs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016652/how-to-send-firebase-cloud-messaging-from-a-node-server/38016996#38016996).