# Notification action buttons action without showing the app

Tags: react-native, notifications, react-native-push-notification

I have a local notification with action buttons 'Start' and 'Remind later'. When I click on either of two, the app opens. I want to keep it for the Start button, but for Remind later button I want to silently run some code (reschedule notification on a later time) without opening an app.

Is this possible to do?

```js
    function onOpened(notification) {
        if (notification.action == 'Start') {
            cancelNotification(notification.id)
            NavigationService.navigate(notification.title)
        } else {
            cancelNotification(notification.id)
            // reschedule
            let dateTime = new Date(notification.fireDate)
            dateTime.setMinutes(dateTime.getMinutes() + 30)
            scheduleNotification(notification.id, notification.title, notification.message, dateTime)
    }
}
```

This code works, but as I said, it bring the app to the foreground, and I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your full code if you looking for help, but from your tags, I assume you are using [React Native Push Notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification). If that's the case you might want to look at this [Action click brings the app from background to foreground](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/945)  issue. Basically, you need to go through some native codes and change a few lines.

Comment: Can you be more specific what do I need to change and where?
I followed your link and there's a commit of an older version saying they fixed it. I have a newer version and I still see this behavior.

Comment: You can either A) uninstall the current version of react-native-push-notifications and install version 3.1.1. or earlier or B) change RNPushNotificationHelper.java according to this link https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/commit/6b732623c62f3b4fdbcc47aa786556ae23da17a7. I personally prefer later choice since I'm used to manually changing files according to my needs

Comment: I have a question, I'm developing two apps first of the user app and second to providers, in user app, I made some function to send order and saved into real-time database firebase t and in the second app I just retrieve the data from DB with a listener to get the new order as a real-time without refreshing the app, SO I want to when I send an order from user app to firebase I want to display a notify in the second app? How to handle these

Comment: @DevAS this is a very easy task if you are using firebase database too. You might check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022413/firebase-notification-on-child-added-modified or https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases