# How can I create a fixed notification bar with React native?

Tags: react-native, custom-notification

how can I create such a fixed notification bar on the notification screen of the device with react native?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create notifications with action buttons in React Native, you'll need to use a combination of the react-native-push-notification library and the react-native-notifications library. Here's a step-by-step guide to achieving this:

Step 1: Install the required packages

```
npm install react-native-push-notification react-native-notifications
```

Step 2: Link the native modules (for React Native < 0.60)

```
react-native link react-native-push-notification
react-native link react-native-notifications
```

Step 3: Configure the notification libraries

Follow the setup instructions for both libraries according to the documentation:

[react-native-push-notification](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/ios/interaction#press-action)

[react-native-notifications](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/ios/interaction#press-action)

[enter link description here](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/ios/interaction#press-action)

[Exempls](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification)

[wix library](https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/getting-started)

[Another stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808166/notification-action-buttons-action-without-showing-the-app)