# Integrate Firebase Database with FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to integrate the Firebase real time database with the newly introduced Firebase Cloud Messaging services ?
I am building an app which uses the the Firebase realtime database for storing data. I want to notify my users using push notifications for every new insert in the database. I  came across tutorials which teach you how to use FCM, but most of them require you to set up your own server for storing tokens.
 Is there a serverless way of integrating Firebase DB with FCM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending messages to devices based on inserts into the Firebase Database will require you to run a trusted process, typically on an app server that you control. This [trusted process listens to the database changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/retrieve-data) and then [calls Firebase Cloud Messaging to send the messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server).

For an example of how to send messaging from a node.js script, see my answer here: [How to send Firebase Cloud Messaging from a node server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016652/how-to-send-firebase-cloud-messaging-from-a-node-server)